# How to export array list to csv file?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, dataframe, arraylist

I am using Python 3.6.8 and I have been searching for a little white but I still cannot get the proper export to csv that I want.

I have a list of 1D array which I am trying to export into a CSV file. each array has a different size, and I want to export them following a column order, meaning each 1D array will be stored into 1 column in the CSV file.

To simplify my code, it will do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_thing = []
a = np.arange(10)
list_of_thing.append(a)
b = np.arange(5)
list_of_thing.append(b)

csvfile = "./data.csv"
my_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_thing)
my_df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False, header=False)
```

I also have tried to use `np.savetext` and using `with open(csvfile, "w") as output:` without much success.

What I am getting is this

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   2   3   4
```

When i wish it look like this

```
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   
6   
7   
8   
9
```

At the place of the append, I am thinking if it is possible to save everytime the array by specifying the column where it should go.

Comment: That csv layout will be hard to read. You could just iterate in python and write the file line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm unsure to why you're forming the df in this way.

use:

```py
my_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_thing)
my_df = my_df.T
my_df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I was not aware we could also use the transform on dataframe directly

Answer (score 0):

Here a different method to input different sized lists to columns, i filled the smaller list with the character "":

```
import pandas as pd

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(5)

maxLen = max(len(a), len(b))

fill_char = ""
a = list(a) + [fill_char]*(maxLen - len(a))
b = list(b) + [fill_char]*(maxLen - len(b))

my_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)),columns=["col1","col2"])

print(my_df)

   col1 col2
0     0    0
1     1    1
2     2    2
3     3    3
4     4    4
5     5     
6     6     
7     7     
8     8     
9     9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip_longest` to 'transpose' the list of arrays with a blank fill value:

```
In [120]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [129]: alist = list(zip_longest(np.arange(10), np.arange(5),fillvalue=''))                                
In [130]: alist                                                                                              
Out[130]: 
[(0, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 4),
 (5, ''),
 (6, ''),
 (7, ''),
 (8, ''),
 (9, '')]
```

(default fillvalue is `None`)

Then just write this to a file, tuple by tuple:

```
In [131]: with open('foobar.txt','w') as f: 
     ...:     for row in alist: 
     ...:         print('{} {}'.format(*row), file=f) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [132]: cat foobar.txt                                                                                     
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 
6 
7 
8 
9
```

This can also be written with savetxt:

```
np.savetxt('foobar.txt',alist, fmt='%s')
```

With the string element, I have to use '%s'`formatting rather than a numeric one.`savetxt` does a row iteration, so isn't any faster.

You may have to play with column width and delimiter, especially if short lists are on the left.